# How do I tell php exec to use 32 bit version of cmd prompt

Tags: php, windows, powershell

I'm running IIS6 on windows server 2008.  I'm trying to call a powershell script via PHPs exec function.

The problem I have is that the powershell script fails when run from the 64bit version of the command prompt. If run from the 32bit command prompt it works fine.

How can i configure PHP to use the 32bit command prompt instead of the 64bit version?

Thanks

Comment: I'll probably add the directory of the 32 bits command prompt to the `PATH` of my server, give it a different name to the executable and try again...

Comment: explictly call %windir%\syswow64\\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the 32-bit version of PowerShell, on a 64-bit system, you can call:

```
$powershell = getenv('WINDIR') . "\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /?";
$output = exec($powershell);
```